# How to programmatically acess an Action from code (WPF)?

Tags: mdriven

It is reletively clear for me how to access Actions in a prototype. But how can I do it in code?

E.g. I would like to execute a Class Action from within a Button. I defined an Action ShowPerson in a ViewModel on class Person. It has been generated in C# as method Execute_ShowPerson(). If I call it on Click event of the button I would expect the Standard View of the defined Bring-Up-View-Model comes, but nothing appears.
I have tried another way defining a new action column on the ViewModel where the Action is opted in, but I have found no way to access it over EAL SelfVM.

How to implement it?

/Efim

Answer (score 0):

To reach into a ViewModel and trigger an action to execute:

```
 (Resources["MyAllPersonsView"] as AllPersonsView).ViewModelClass.ViewModel.ExecuteAction("MyAllPersonsView", "NameOfAction");
```

To Bring up other windows etc a good deal of knowledge must be had by the application - this is handled by wecpof - and if you want to react to such events you would implement OnBringUpView like this:

```
(Resources["MyAllPersonsView"] as AllPersonsView).ViewModelClass.ViewModel.OnBringUpView += (s, args) => {args. }
```

Args will have rootobject, viewname and the action that brought this about.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more how to implement it? If I call (Resources["MyAllPersonsView"] as AllPersonsView).ViewModelClass.ViewModel.ExecuteAction("MyAllPersonsView", "ShowPerson"); in button event handler I get "Could not find action". How to implement   OnBringUpView an when will it fire?

Comment: Bringing up views can be fairly complex - they could be modal, and then the aftermodalok expression of the action should possibly be executed. But this is all standard c# and WPF with exception of MDriven bringing you the meta-data on what the goal is (ie what viewmodel name constitutes the new view, what root object should it have) - you are free to implement whatever you need - and if you want to done exactly as in the model use the ViewModelWPFUserControl as described here https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/ViewModel

Comment: Yes, it works with ViewModelWPFUserControl but it is not complitely reusable. E.g. if I bring up an AutoForm on this way I can't navigate it further over associations-buttons. And the Datetime-field Birthday is not filled out(why?)